On AdButton clicked the mobile app closes immediately
I am trying to implement rewarded Ads on an application but whenever I click the ad button that came with the application the app closes immediately and I get sent to the Home screen.
N.B: I am not using the android emulator, I am using my phone
This is what the app looks like and the ad button on the right:

This is the error I keep getting on my logcat:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:93)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:134)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:128)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:612)
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:206)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:603)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:572)

I have a RewardedAdActivity class that implement the rewarded Ad logic, I will provide it to see if I had any flaws:
class RewardedAdActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private companion object {
        const val TAG = "REWARDED_AD_TAG"
    }

    private lateinit var loadAndShowAdBtn: Button//1st fault since button watch ad is not of type material button
    private lateinit var loadAdBtn: Button

    private var mRewardedAd: RewardedAd? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rewarded_ad)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        title = "Rewarded Ad"

        MobileAds.initialize(this) { initStatus ->
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $initStatus")
        }

        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
            RequestConfiguration.Builder()
                .setTestDeviceIds(listOf("D2EEC432076C32ACAF2BC1986D627B4E"))
                .build()
        )

        loadAndShowAdBtn = findViewById(R.id.loadAndShowAdButton)

        loadAndShowAdBtn.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.button_watch_ad)

//How do i add the ad functionality to the already existing ad button
        // and also how do i add an on click listener to the already existing ad button
        //or how do i reference loadAndShowAdButton to the already existing ad button
        // or do i put the code in game screen
        loadAndShowAdBtn.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndShowRewardedAd()
        }
    }

    fun showRewardedAd() {
        if (mRewardedAd != null) {
            mRewardedAd!!.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdClicked() {
                    super.onAdClicked()
                    /*Called when an Ad is clicked*/
                }

                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                    /*Called when an ad is dismissed/closed*/
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: ")
                    mRewardedAd = null
                    //loadAndShowRewardedAd()
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError)
                    /*Called when an ad is failed to show*/
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent ${adError.message}")
                    mRewardedAd = null
                }

                override fun onAdImpression() {
                    super.onAdImpression()
                    /*Called when an Impression is recorded*/
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAdImpression: ")
                }

                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent()
                    /*Called when an ad is shown*/
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent: ")
                }
            }

            mRewardedAd!!.show(this) {
                /*Called when user has completely watched and AD*/
                Log.d(TAG, "onRewardEarned")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Reward Earned...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            //Ad was not loaded
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ad wasn't loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    fun loadAndShowRewardedAd() {
        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait")
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Rewarded Ad...!")
        progressDialog.show()

        RewardedAd.load(
            this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            AdRequest.Builder().build(),
            object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(adError)
                    //Called when an Ad is failed to load
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ${adError.message}")
                    mRewardedAd = null
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@RewardedAdActivity,
                        "Failed to load Ad${adError.message}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                        .show()
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(rewardedAd: RewardedAd) {
                    super.onAdLoaded(rewardedAd)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ")
                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    showRewardedAd()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

The button is a drawable and I called it in the class above and set it as the background for the button I already have in my activity_rewarded_ad.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".RewardedAdActivity">

    <!--    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/loadAndShowAdButton"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:text="@string/ad"/>-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadAndShowAdButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_watch_ad" />
</LinearLayout>

To make this short I called it finally in to my gaamescreen.kt where I am meant to show the ad which is this line:
PreviewWord(
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Center),
    viewmodel = viewModel,
)
if (mGems < GEMS_TO_CONSUME) {

    //Ad
    val adbuttonmodifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
    ButtonWatchAd(
        modifier = adbuttonmodifier,
        showHand = showHand
    ) {
        //Show your add here
        rewardedAdActivity.showRewardedAd()//this is where i called it in
    }
}
LaunchedEffect(showHand) {
    if (showHand) {
        delay(3000)
        showHand = false
    }
}


Somewhere you are calling makeText() with a null Context. Debug your app to find where, then make sure it's not null.
